# Lex priority label opcode priority

Tags: lex

I am using lex / yacc to write an assembler

I have some opcodes for example

```
ORA                             [Oo][Rr][Aa]
AND                             [Aa][Nn][Dd]
EOR                             [Ee][Oo][Rr]
```

and rules

```
{ORA}                           { yylval.iValue = ora; return OPCODE; }
{AND}                           { yylval.iValue = and; return OPCODE; }
{EOR}                           { yylval.iValue = eor; return OPCODE; }
```

I also have rules for labels

```
    [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*:         { yylval.sIndex = AddSymbol(yytext);  return SYMBOL; }
    [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*          { yylval.sIndex = AddSymbol(yytext);  return SYMBOL; }

labels in the syntax can be

    ldx #$FF
loop:
    sta $5535,X
    dex
    bne loop
```

The problem is it will match the label instead of the opcodes.
The first label rule works because of the ':' but the second label rule takes presidence over the opcode rule.

Is there a way for me to get the second case to the label to work(the bne loop)?

Thanks in advance.

I am fairly new to lex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the opcode rules come before the catch-all identifier rule. If two rules both apply to the longest matched token, (f)lex generated scanners choose the first one in the source.

Definitions do not alter the priority of rules. What is important is the order of the rules themselves.

---

By the way, you might want to consider making `:` a token by itself, rather than merging both instances of `loop` (one a definition and the other one a use) into the same token type.

Including the colon in the token, as you do, prevents the user from putting whitespace between the label name and the <kbd>:</kbd>, but that might be your intent. And in some grammars, a two-token label definition causes the grammar to be `LR(2)` instead of `LR(1)`.

In any case, you will almost certainly find it simpler if you mark the definition as a definition by giving it a different token type.